# sql server: storing datetime vs long text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a situation which I can resolve by adding a column which would be a datetime or a ntext type.

In terms of performace, which of these would be better to use. The number of records are more than 60000. I was thinking datetime since I could index on it, but not sure if ntext can be...any suggestion or discussion on which would handle memory,speed better...or any other performance issues?

Update: the column i will add are independent- one is date time and other is text, i can resolve the issue by having anyone, NOTE: I am not trying to store datetime as ntext here.

Comment: Have you really just asked "Should I store a date-time as a DATETIME or something else"?

Comment: I am not asking for store datetime as string, they are two different feilds

Comment: Please explain more about your situation and why you have to choose between these 2 columns?

Comment: AS of SQL Server 2005, `TEXT` and `NTEXT` are **deprecated** - do **not** use those anymore, especially when developing new code and databases. Use `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `NVARCHAR(MAX)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

60000 records is nothing for SQL Server.
So there shouldn't be any noticeable difference. Maybe there would be a difference if it was a REALLY big table (hundreds of millions of records, and above...), but not with your amount of data.

However, as the others already said: your statement that you can either use datetime or ntext sounds very strange to me. If it's really date and/or time values, use `datetime` and not `ntext`!!!

---

**EDIT:**

Now that you clarified that you don't want to store date values in a text column:
I would suggest that you use the `datetime` column. It's better than `ntext` performance wise.

As a side note: if you prefer to use the text column, you should use `nvarchar(max)` instead of `ntext`. `ntext` is slower and deprecated.

Comment: There will be a noticeable difference. If stored using the frankly bizarre `ntext` proposal it will be stored off row by default.

Comment: I know that using `ntext` is a bad idea (read the rest of my answer), and I know that using `ntext` is slower, but I doubt that there will be a human noticeable difference with only 60000 records.

Answer (score 2):

If the data is a `DATETIME`, use a `DATETIME`.

You will have problems querying a text field when you need to do date and time operations.

Performance wise - `DATETIME` is 8 bytes and `NVARCHAR` for storing a date will be longer. Operations that require date/time work will require conversions with an `NVARCHAR` field, which will be more expensive than simply using a `DATETIME` column.

Answer (score 1):

These are two completely different fields.  If you need to store dates use datetime, if you need to store text use varchar or long text.  Do not store dates as text!